# timeoutlen breaks <leader> and vim-commentary

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc

I installed vim-airline about 2 weeks ago. At that time I read a section in the [FAQs](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline/wiki/FAQ) about a delay occurring after exiting insert mode and into normal mode. I noticed the delay and applied the fix suggested by adding `timeoutlen=50` to my `.vimrc`. After setting that vim-commentary started to not work. I would issue the command `gcc` and vim would do nothing until I hit hjkl or an arrow key, at which vim would delete the line and enter insert mode. I also noticed that my maps that used `<leader>` wouldn't work. Vim would skip a few characters and then enter visual mode.

I narrowed the problem down to the `timeoutlen=50`. I then set it to `timeoutlen=1000 ttimeoutlen=10` and that resolved all the problems. Now, could anyone explain what's going on with vim when `timeoutlen` is set to a number like 50? Why was I having such weird issues? and why is everything resolved by setting `timeoutlen` to a much higher number and setting `ttimeoutlen`? and why did the FAQ suggest 50 when it created these errors?

Comment: I have installed vim-airline and `timeoutlen`, `ttimeoutlen` and `esckeys` is default (`timeoutlen=1000 ttimeoutlen=-1 esckeys timeout nottimeout`) and have no any problems, and no delay after exiting insert mode. By the way `:he timeoutlen`, `:he timeout`, `:he esckeys` should explain you I hope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this post](https://www.johnhawthorn.com/2012/09/vi-escape-delays/) explains the difference between `timeoutlen` and `ttimeoutlen` nicely, especially when used to fix issues with airline/powerline:

> Another solution is to use [`timeoutlen` and `ttimeoutlen`](http://www.polarhome.com/vim/manual/v57/options.html#%27timeoutlen%27). `timeoutlen` is used for mapping delays, and `ttimeoutlen` is used for key code delays. My `.vimrc` has:
>
> `set timeoutlen=1000 ttimeoutlen=0`
>
> It might be more reasonable to give `ttimeoutlen` a more reasonable value, like 10ms, although I have encountered no issues yet.
>
> This is especially nice with vim-powerline, which gives clear visual indication of the current mode.